# MATLAB: Partition vector in multiple parts using begin and end indices

Tags: matlab, data-partitioning

I have an `1xN` array with data, from which I want to cut out the relevant parts.
Basically I have two arrays - `beginIndex` and `endIndex` - that indicate which parts of data I need to extract.

**Example:**

```
data = 1:10;
beginIndex = [1 5 9];
endIndex = [3 6 10];
```

The desired result would be

```
partitionedData = [1 2 3 5 6 9 10] %Indices: 1-3, 5-6, 9-10
```

I already tried

```
partitionedData = data(beginIndex:endIndex)
```

The latter gives me the equivalent to

```
partitionedData = data(beginIndex(1):endIndex(1)) %[1 2 3]
```

Also I tried [accumarray](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html), but the aggregation function must return scalar values.
I would really appreciate some help here.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
>> partitionedData = data(cell2mat(arrayfun(@(s,e) s:e, beginIndex, endIndex, ...
    'uni', 0)))
partitionedData =
     1     2     3     5     6     9    10
```

Comment: You've been faster than me :-( Don't forget to index `data` with your result

Comment: Thanks, forgot the indexing. That is why you should never use 1:10 as test input, if you use 10:20, you see the problem directly.

Answer (score 1):

In one line :-)

```
data(cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x,y) x:y, beginIndex,endIndex,'UniformOutput',false)))
```